# The application of squeeze theorem in limit situation

Tags: calculus, limits

We have a function $f(m)$. Now, if for any $k \in (0,1)$, there is 
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} f(m)-k\ln(m)\geq0$$
Furthermore, we have 
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} f(m)-\ln(m)\leq0$$

Can we conclude that $\lim_{m\to \infty} f(m)-\ln(m)=0$ by Squeeze Theorem?

If not, is there any more property that $f(m)$ needs to satisfy to justify the statement?

Answer (score 1):

No. You might try to ask what exactly it is that you think you are "squeezing" your function between.

For instance, it's not hard to come up with an explicit counterexample. Suppose $f(m,k)$ is the function which assigns $-1$ to all $m$ when $k < 1$ and $1$ when $k \geq 1$. Then this $f$ satisfies your conditions, but never actually takes the value $0$.

Comment: I just made some edition to provide more details to $f(m,k)$, could the statement hold after edition?